# What's exactly an alias in C?

Tags: c, alias

If I have:

```
int a= 10;

int *ptr = &a;
int *ptr_2 = ptr;
```

It's said that `*ptr` and not `ptr` is an alias of `a` but is `ptr_2` an alias of `ptr` or is `*ptr_2` an alias of `*ptr`?

I know that, generally speaking, when two or more objects refer one memory address than they are aliases. So in relationship of this assertion I could think that `ptr_2` and `ptr` are alias but I'm not sure because the relationship of `*ptr` and `a`...

So what is, from C perspective, an alias?

Answer (score 1):

am answering the part "I'm not sure because the relationship of *ptr and a", I think the rest is already clear to you.

In C each variable has a value and an address. The latter specifies where the variable is located in the memory and it is unique for a program. `int a` declares a variable with some address say `&a`. Now, when you assign `10` to `a` then value `10` is placed at address `&a`.

When you declare `int *ptr = &a`, a new variable `ptr` is declared with address `&ptr` and value `&a`.
Now, since the type of `ptr` is `int*` so you can directly go to the address stored in the variable `ptr` by using `*ptr`. This is called [dereferencing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator).

Essentially when you write `*ptr` in you program then it means the value of the address stored in `ptr` , which in case is `10` . If you do an assignment at a later point with `*ptr = 20`, then the value at address stored in `ptr` is changed to 20. In this case that address stored in `ptr` is `&a` so the value of `a` will be changed to `20`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this wiki on [Pointer aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing) for a good explanation

> aliasing refers to the situation where the same memory location can be
>   accessed using different names.
>
> For instance, if a function takes two pointers A and B which have the
>   same value, then the name A[0] aliases the name B[0]. In this case we
>   say the pointers A and B alias each other. Note that the concept of
>   pointer aliasing is not very well-defined – two pointers A and B may
>   or may not alias each other, depending on what operations are
>   performed in the function using A and B. For instance, in memcpy(A +
>   8, A, 8), where A is a pointer to type char, the destination and
>   source pointers do not alias, but in memmove(A + 8, A, 9) they do.

Comment: This wiki is also contradictory: it says that A and B alias each other but also that A[0], that is *A, and B[0], that is *B, are alias...

Comment: @xdevel2000 The wiki says that ` aliasing refers to the situation where the same memory location can be accessed using different names.` Now, as `A` and `B` have same value so `*A` and `*B` refer to the same address space, i.e the same memory location.

Comment: @Nishant, so it seems to understand, that A and B are alias because  they have, as value, the same address; also *A and *B are alias because they'are dereferncing the same address...

Answer (score -2):

alias mean which share same memory location
int x = 50;
int& y = x;

now x and y share same memory location. *ptr is pointer variable and point other variable.